# Determine if binary file changed while resolving "both added" git conflict

Tags: git, binaryfiles, rebase, merge-conflict-resolution

I'm performing a rebase, and encounter "both added" conflicts for binary files.  I want to accept 'ours' if the binary files are the same, 'theirs' if they are changed.  During the resolve, how can I test if the binary files are same or different?

Comment: If they're the same, why would it matter which you took?

Answer (score 1):

You will not get a conflict if the files match.

Let's show this by example.  Although you are talking about rebase (vs merge), conflicts are handled the same way, since it's the same code involved:

```
$ mkdir addadd; cd addadd; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/torek/tmp/addadd/.git/
$ echo a repository for testing add/add conflict > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) f665e86] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
```

Now we need some binary files.  I will use `/bin/ls` and `/bin/cat`, and put identical binaries under one name into two branches, and non-identical versions under one name into two more branches:

```
$ git checkout -b b1 master
Switched to a new branch 'b1'
$ cp /bin/ls some-file
$ git add some-file && git commit -m 'add some-file on b1'
[b1 5128ae4] add some-file on b1
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 some-file
$ git checkout -b b2 master
Switched to a new branch 'b2'
$ cp /bin/ls some-file
$ git add some-file && git commit -m 'add some-file on b2'
[b2 0e7d771] add some-file on b2
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 some-file
```

Now we try merging `b1` into `b2` or vice versa.  We're already on `b2` so let's merge `b1` here:

```
$ git merge --no-edit b1
Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
*   257e77a (HEAD -> b2) Merge branch 'b1' into b2
|\  
| * 5128ae4 (b1) add some-file on b1
* | 0e7d771 add some-file on b2
|/  
* f665e86 (master) initial
```

Now let's try the same thing with differing binaries:

```
$ git checkout -b b3 master
Switched to a new branch 'b3'
$ cp /bin/ls some-file
$ git add some-file && git commit -m 'add some-file on b3'
[b3 2ede434] add some-file on b3
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 some-file
$ git checkout -b b4 master
Switched to a new branch 'b4'
$ cp /bin/cat some-file 
$ git add some-file && git commit -m 'add different some-file on b4'
[b4 9e5f2cf] add different some-file on b4
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100755 some-file
```

Again, we'll merge `b3` into `b4` here:

```
$ git merge --no-edit b3
warning: Cannot merge binary files: some-file (HEAD vs. b3)
Auto-merging some-file
CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in some-file
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
$ git status --short
AA some-file
```

This time, the merge failed with an add/add conflict.  That means the files were different: the previous merge succeeded because the files were the same.  The merge is not complete but we can still look at the commit graph:

```
$ git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all
* 9e5f2cf (HEAD -> b4) add different some-file on b4
| * 2ede434 (b3) add some-file on b3
|/  
| *   257e77a (b2) Merge branch 'b1' into b2
| |\  
| | * 5128ae4 (b1) add some-file on b1
| |/  
|/|   
| * 0e7d771 add some-file on b2
|/  
* f665e86 (master) initial
```

Interestingly, when the files are the same, we do not even get the warning message.  This is because Git's merge machinery bypasses all the usual merge code when the files match.<sup>1</sup>  In particular, custom merge drivers from `.gitattributes` files are never run.

We can see the files are different (and that there was an add/add conflict) by running `git ls-files --stage`:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 661d9d91972de27e4f787e3ad93ea3b7a1741ddf 0   README
100755 b75a044e06fb5e093a547c4ef9a388313d27f79a 2   some-file
100755 2ca93e76b4dedc9970cca9a708ab1cb94ca032ee 3   some-file
```

Pathname `some-file` exists as stages 2 and 3, but not as stage 1 (base).  This means there was no base version of the file: so this is an add/add conflict.  The hash for stage 2, `--ours`, is `b75a044...`, and the hash for stage 3 or `--theirs` is `2ca93e7...`, which we can also see with `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse :2:some-file
b75a044e06fb5e093a547c4ef9a388313d27f79a
```

(repeat for `:3:some-file` if desired).

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, Git simply checks whether the index entry's hash matches the hash in the other or `--theirs` commit.  If so, it is by definition the same file, and no merge action is required.